# Why Gitlab skips job for merge-request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have empty project with `.gitlab-ci.yml`. In the branch `test` in has the only commit with the following content:

```yaml
job1:
  script:
    - echo param1
      param2

job1 always:
  script:
    - echo param1
      param2
  rules:
    - when: always

job1 on_success:
  script:
    - echo param1
      param2
  rules:
    - when: on_success
```

Also I create a merge-request for `test` → `main`.

For this commit it runs to pipelines:

- for commit in branch
- for merge request

[image: two-pipelines]

Pipeline for branch contains three jobs:

- `job1`
- `job1 always`
- `job1 on_success`

[image: has-job1]

But pipeline for merge request does NOT contain `job1` job:

[image: missing-job1-in-mr]

---

A few questions are arised:

1. Why is `job1` skipped in merge-request pipelines?

   (Tested on Gitlab and 15.7 and 16.2).
2. As mentioned [hackinteachk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76686346/3364871), According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html):

   > "[jobs] Do not run by default."

   It is ok for `job1`. But `job1 on_success` isn't related with rules for merge-request pipelines (not contains `if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'`). Why is `job1 on_success` running during MR?
3. I created another project with pipeline in the branch `test`:

   ```yaml
   job1:
     script:
       - echo OK
   ```

   During merge-request, Gitlab refers to pipeline on branch, and not create new pipeline for merge-request. Why?
4. If I append `rules` to previous job:

   ```yaml
   job1:
     script:
       - echo OK
     rules:
       - when: always # or on_success
   ```

   then Gitlab creates MR-pipeline. Such rules are not in [prerequisites](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#prerequisites). When pipeline is considered as to create MR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html), merge requests pipeline doesn't run by default unless you specify condition for the jobs. In this case, `job1 always` and `job1 on_success` have `rules.when` condition on them.

Comment: "Do not run by default." is ok for `job1`. But `job1 on_success` isn't related with `rules` for merge-request pipelines (not contains `if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'`). Why is `job1 on_success` running during MR?

Comment: I have add this and a few other questions to the question message. Could you please update your answer to consider them as well?

Comment: i think `on_success` only need prior jobs to be success and it'll run regardless of the triggered source. For `always`, run the job regardless of any conditions.